# Variable Route Not Working in For Loop

Tags: python, flask

I tried to create multiple routes in one go by using the variables from the database and a for loop.

I tried this

```
temp = "example"
@app.route("/speaker/<temp>")
def getSpeakerAtr(temp):
    return  '''%s''' % temp
```

It works very well. BUT:

```
for x in models.Speaker.objects:
        temp = str(x.name)
        @app.route("/speaker/<temp>")
        def getSpeakerAtr(temp):
            return  '''%s''' % temp
```

Doesn't work. The error message:

File "/Users/yang/Documents/CCPC-Website/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1013, in decorator
02:03:04 web.1  |     self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)

**The reason I want to use multiple routes is that I need to get the full data of an object by querying from the route. For example:
if we type this url:

//.../speaker/sam

we can get the object who has the 'name' value as 'sam'. Then I can use all of the values in this object like bio or something.**

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong with this design because the `temp` parameter in function call `getSpeakerAtr(temp)` will hide the `temp` that is defined above the `getSpeakerAtr`. The value of `temp` inside `getSpeakerAtr` will always be what was given as part of URL after its `/speaker/` portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple routes. Just one route that validates its value, eg:

```
@app.route('/speaker/<temp>')
def getSpeakerAtr(temp):
    if not any(temp == str(x.name) for x in models.Speaker.objects):
        # do something appropriate (404 or something?)
    # carry on doing something else
```

Or as to your real intent:

```
@app.route('/speaker/<name>')
def getSpeakerAtr(name):
    speaker = # do something with models.Speaker.objects to lookup `name`
    if not speaker: # or whatever check is suitable to determine name didn't exist
        # raise a 404, or whatever's suitable
    # we have a speaker object, so use as appropriate
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but i am very new to back-end dev. I added some more info in the question, can you take a look and help me to customize the code a little bit?

Comment: @yang okay, you still don't need multiple routes like I've already said. You have a single route, then use the value passed to do the lookup... If you had a database of 10million names, you don't need/want 10million routes to handle it. Take `temp` or `name` or whatever you're calling it, then use `models.Speaker.objects` to do a lookup for that name to get your object. If it can't find it, 404 or something, otherwise, use the object returned as you wish

Comment: I got the idea. Pretty smart. But instead of the code ( I could't understand how it works.. ), I used a more primitive solution:   theSpeaker = models.Speaker.objects.get(name=name)